# get time without time zone in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, date

I have a function in postgreSQL that has a time without time zone column. Then in my method, I get an error when setting the parameter. It says the type is unknown. How can I set this parameter with the current system time? The purpose of the method is to verify if the register exists or not in DB.

Function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.inserir_posicao(
    _tag bigint,
    _data_hora timestamp without time zone,
    _lat double precision,
    _long double precision,
    _gado_id bigint)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$declare
  tagPesq BigInt;
begin

  select tag into tagPesq from coordenadas where tag = $1;
  if tagPesq is not null and tagPesq > 0 then
     update coordenadas set pos_data = $2, 
    pos_latitude = $3,
    pos_longitude = $4,
    gado_id = $5
    where tag_id = $1;
  else
     insert into coordenadas(pos_data,pos_latitude,pos_longitude,
    tag_id, gado_id) values ($2,$3,$4,$1,$5);
  end if;

  return 1;

  EXCEPTION WHEN RAISE_EXCEPTION THEN
  BEGIN
    return 0;
  END;
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.inserir_posicao(bigint, time with time zone, double precision, double precision, bigint)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Method:

```
public int insertPosicao(BigInteger tagId, BigInteger gadoId, double lat, double lon) {

        Query qry = manager.createNativeQuery("select inserir_posicao(:tag,:data,:lat,:lng,:gado)");
        qry.setParameter("tag", tagId);
        qry.setParameter("data", ??? ); //this parameter.
        qry.setParameter("lat", lat);
        qry.setParameter("lng", lon);
        qry.setParameter("gado", gadoId);
        return (int) qry.getSingleResult();
    }
```

Comment: _"I have a function in postgreSQL"_ -- show us the function.  What type does it expect?  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use StackOverflow effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umh you could use something like

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(**pattern**);
String sData = sdf.format(GregorianCalendar.getInstance());
qry.setParameter("date",sData);
```

where you have to specify you **pattern**

In my code I put `GregorianCalendar.getInstance` that return current time. You can also achieve this with just a `sysdate` on query.
On your function, on

`pos_data = $2` you have to set `pos_data=to_date($2,**pattern**)` because now, you pass a String stands for date and via postgres function you transfor it into date

See also: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [to_date PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: I used the first three lines you wrote. Should it get right? because I get the error:Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: You have to specify a pattern, something like 'yyyy/MM/dd'. The pattern has to be a String. Look at link in my reply

Comment: why doesnt it get right if I use qry.setParameter("data", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

Comment: Did you change also function on postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, only in Java 8, to get a local time offset to UTC and without a zone:

```
String ldt = Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime().toString();
qry.setParameter("data",ldt);
```

If you have your own date, you can use the same code just replace `Instant.now()` with `Instant.parse(date)`, though it must be formatted properly.