# Get today's date in Timestamp

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a function in postgreSQL that returns 0 or 1 according to its parameters, and I have a method which access this funtion but when I run I get the error, I am having problems in setting the current date in timestamps. I tried to add pattern with simpleDataFormat, and many other things but I couldnt do it. Thanks in advance!

```
 ERROR: function inserir_posicao(numeric, bigint, double precision, double precision, numeric) does not exist
  Dica: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Funtion in db:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.inserir_posicao(
    _tag bigint,
    _data_hora timestamp without time zone,
    _lat double precision,
    _long double precision,
    _gado_id bigint)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$declare
  tagPesq BigInt;
begin

  select tag into tagPesq from coordenadas where tag = $1;
  if tagPesq is not null and tagPesq > 0 then
     update coordenadas set pos_data = $2, 
    pos_latitude = $3,
    pos_longitude = $4,
    gado_id = $5
    where tag_id = $1;
  else
     insert into coordenadas(pos_data,pos_latitude,pos_longitude,
    tag_id, gado_id) values ($2,$3,$4,$1,$5);
  end if;

  return 1;

  EXCEPTION WHEN RAISE_EXCEPTION THEN
  BEGIN
    return 0;
  END;
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.inserir_posicao(bigint, timestamp without time zone, double precision, double precision, bigint)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Method:

```
public int inserirPosicao(BigInteger tagId, BigInteger gadoId, double lat, double lon) {
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());  


        Query qry = manager.createNativeQuery("select inserir_posicao(:tag,:data,:lat,:lng,:gado)");
        qry.setParameter("tag", tagId);
        qry.setParameter("data", timestamp.getTime());
        qry.setParameter("lat", lat);
        qry.setParameter("lng", lon);
        qry.setParameter("gado", gadoId);
        return (int) qry.getSingleResult();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get time without time zone in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106041/get-time-without-time-zone-in-java)

Comment: Your problem is in this line: qry.setParameter("data", timestamp.getTime());   please, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
qry.setParameter("data", timestamp.getTime());
```

The method [getTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) returns the date/time in miliseconds since 01/01/1970, which is a biginteger number. But your function expects a timestamp value, so you get this error you said.

**Solution:**

You have to pass a "date/time" value as a formated string like "yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss" and then set the parameter as a string...

... or if you want to still passing the date in miliseconds, you have to "convert" this bigint number to a date/time, by changing the line:

```
Query qry = manager.createNativeQuery("select inserir_posicao(:tag,:data,:lat,:lng,:gado)");
```

to

```
Query qry = manager.createNativeQuery("select inserir_posicao(:tag, to_timestamp(:data / 1000) ,:lat,:lng,:gado)");
```

The reason we have to divide `:data` by `1000` is because `to_timestamp` expects the number of seconds since 01/01/1970, and you are passing the number of milliseconds.

> A single-argument to_timestamp function is also available; it accepts
>   a double precision argument and converts from Unix epoch (seconds
>   since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00) to timestamp with time zone. (Integer
>   Unix epochs are implicitly cast to double precision.)

Comment: Thanks for your Help Christian! I got it.]